# Disabling right click and popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to disable right-click on an image. When a user right-clicks on an image, I want it to show a message (please run the code snippet below).

In the code below, I have two images. If I right-click on the top of the image, it pops up a window and says "Right click not allowed". However, if I scroll down and right-click on the image, this pop-up window shows up at the bottom of the website.

Can you please tell me how can I make this pop-up window open up at the place where I am right-clicking? (for example, if I right-click on the second image, this popup window doesn't even show up).

```html
<script>
  if (document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      $("#rmenu").toggleClass("hide");
      $("#rmenu").css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: e.pageY,
        left: e.pageX
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  }
  $(document).bind("click", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("rmenu").className = "hide";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The code shown is for testing purposes to learn about the subject. It is not to annoy anyone.

Comment: Okay, for learning purposes, that's fine. It just drives me insane when people do it in the real world without justification. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicate `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`. Here:

```
...
$("#rmenu").css({
  position: "absolute",
  top: e.pageY,
  left: e.pageX
});
...
```

Comment: @DP., Try setting up an event with a target specifically for img tag, like here - http://jsfiddle.net/T32ZV/

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Well i will suggest you to convert your images or whole HTML page into canvas.If the purpose is to hide code or not to download images.